# Reading list for JT/SYK correspondence

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, holographic-principle, duality

I have been studying Gábor Sárosi's [review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08482) of holographic duality between Jackiw-Teitelboim gravity and the Sachdev-Ye-Kitaev models for the last few days. This field has grown since the review came out in 2017 and so I was looking for a set of recent (or even past that was not mentioned in the review) important papers that should be studied. I have seen that people have constructed the [supersymmetric SYK](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08917) and have also put [2D gauge theories in JT gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05253). Since SYK also has important applications in condensed matter, I was wondering if there is any recent work trying to apply this duality there. I would welcome any recommendation for reading.